# update single table with a 4 table join. Update single column in table 2 with info from 1, 2, and 4

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle Database

Select statement is as follows:

```
SELECT A.DTYP_ID, B.KEM_CLSF, C.KEM_CAT, C.KEM_CLSF, D.DOC_CLSF_ID, D.Dtyp_ID
FROM  AB_CR A, AB_CR_LN B, AB_BD_LN C, AB_BD D
WHERE A.UIDY = B.PARN_OF_LINE_ID
AND B.REFD_LINE_ID = C.UIDY
AND C.PARN_OF_LINE_ID = D.UIDY
AND (a.dtyp_id like '%LR%' or a.dtyp_id like '%CO%')
and B.KEM_CLSF != 'D'
AND D.DTYP_ID LIKE '%AR%'
AND D.DOC_CLSF_ID LIKE '%LNRP%';
```

Need to do the following:

```
update B.KEM_CLSF to 'D'
where (a.dtyp_id like '%LR%' or a.dtyp_id like '%CO%')
    and B.KEM_CLSF != 'D'
    AND D.DTYP_ID LIKE '%AR%'
    AND D.DOC_CLSF_ID LIKE '%LNRP%';
```

BUt i cant figure out how to join the tables properly to do so!

Comment: Utilizing Oracle- Sql Developer

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery to get rows from AB_CR_LN table satisfied to the condition - something like below (I didn't test it and the code can contain mistakes):

```
UPDATE AB_CR_LN B
SET B.KEM_CLSF = 'D'    
WHERE B.KEM_CLSF != 'D'
AND EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM  AB_CR A, AB_BD_LN C, AB_BD D
WHERE A.UIDY = B.PARN_OF_LINE_ID
AND B.REFD_LINE_ID = C.UIDY
AND C.PARN_OF_LINE_ID = D.UIDY
AND (a.dtyp_id like '%LR%' or a.dtyp_id like '%CO%')
AND D.DTYP_ID LIKE '%AR%'
AND D.DOC_CLSF_ID LIKE '%LNRP%'
)
```